# Sequence of number pairs

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

Im trying to figure out which topic this falls under:
Two numbers  (x,y) where the next pair is generated by doubling the smaller one and subtracting the smaller from the larger so if x is smaller (x*2,y-x)

There are number pairs where this will lead to x=y or y=x e.g (1,3) --> (2,2).
And other pairs where no end is reached e.g (3,4) --> (6,1) --> (5,2)  --> (3,4)
I need an algorithm to know which number pairs, from a list,will give me the second sequence

Ive tried plotting looking into cyclic permutations no luck.
Any help or what topic I need to read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read chapter 1 of Arthur Engel's Problem Solving Strategies.

Define $(a_{i},b_{i})$ as the pair after $i$ iteration. Two observations:

$a_{n+1}+b_{n+1}=a_{n}+b_{n}$ and either $GCD(a_{n+1},b_{n+1})=GCD(a_{i},b_{i})$ or $GCD(a_{n+1},b_{n+1})=2\times GCD(a_{i},b_{i})$

Ends will be reached if $\frac{a_{0}+b_{0}}{GCD(a_{0},b_{0})}=2^{k}, k\in\mathbb{Z}$. I leave the proof of this last part to You

Comment: Thank you so very much! This absolutely works. I've gotten the book recommendation and I will read.Stay blessed.